# Is there any way to display notes on a cell when the Excel workbook is embeded in a webpage via iframe?

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, iframe

I'm trying to display an embedded spreadsheet on a webpage. It must freeze the top row and first column for ease of navigation (which Google sheets can't do when embedded). The other thing I need it to do is display more information to a user about specific cells.

I thought Notes would accomplish the task of showing text when a user mouses over the cell but notes only display in the threaded comment sidebar which is awful for this situation. Also apparently they don't display at all if you limit the frame to a cell range. I then thought a Data Validation message might accomplish the task but they don't seem to function in the iframe either.

Does anyone know of a method for displaying text when hovering over a cell (or by clicking on a cell) that work on an embeded spreadsheet?